# Insufficient data in cloudwatch for dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am using dynamodb table with GSI(Global Index).and I am getting **insufficient** alarm with **Insufficient_data** state, **threshold** ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits >= 240 for 60 datapoints within 1 hour,**Treat missing data as** missing,**static** sum,**Period** 1 min,**Statistic** sum
  I have default Read and Write capacity with 5 units and autoscaling off.
What action should need to do for smoothly working database table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *insufficient data* in CloudWatch alarms refers to the metrics data points that the alram is configured against. It doesn't mean there is insufficient data in the table (or GSI).

The fact that there is insufficient data for the alarm, usually, indicates that there wasn't much activity on the underlying resource being monitored. In most cases, this is fine, and you can configure the alarm to ignore the missing data.

For a DynamoDB table, when you don't have activity on the table, you will not get metrics for ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits. This is normal, though it could be indicative of a problem if you expected there to be activity within a period of time but there was none.

Read more about CloudWatch alarms here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html